# What kind of issues should I watch out for or avoid when using JOGL(OpenGL Java bindings)?

Tags: opengl, java, jogl

I am completely new to OpenGL, but have a very good basic foundation in Java. I've set up Eclipse with the most recent version of JOGL recently, having found it to be, of what I as a beginner programmer, feel as very easily adaptable from the original OpenGL code. By simply using a replace all command to change the C++ native library commands from gl to gl.gl, and GL_ETC to glu.GL2_ETC, and so on and using a website with OpenGL tutorials on nehe.gamedev.net that I recently found, I was wondering if there are any huge problems or things I should avoid for instance using awt or swing as a frame or window for a viewport program. Maybe I'm trying to ask a more specific question before I even try it on my own, and that is, "Do I use windows from both languages consecutively or would it just create two windows, whilst trying to only open one window?", as they both have similar methods and objects aside from OpenGL being much more centered on 3D graphics. The reason I ask is that the 3D graphics of OpenGL usually must be built on a frame as far as I know, or linked to the main method of course like anything.

Comment: Forget about nehe, it is outdated. You should learn the modern OpenGL, here an [Hello Triangle](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Jogl_Tutorial#Hello_Triangle).

Answer (score 1):

You generally use a window provided with the library that supports OpenGL. I don't have any experience with JOGL but it seems it works with Swing, although apperantly with a small performance penalty.

LWJGL, another alternative for OpenGL in Java provides a window library with it which is native to C/C++ and is normally used for OpenGL rendering.

Comment: This is why we have Newt now in Jogl